# Javascript "onChange" doesn't trigger on element value change

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, onchange

My approximate HTML:

```
<td style="width: 25%">
  <label class="io-label" for="custom_automation_status">Automation Status <span class="form-required">*</span>
  </label>
  <select name="dropdown_status" style="display: none;">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1"> Option 1</option>
    <option value="2"> Option 2</option>
    <option value="3"> Option 3</option>
    <option value="4"> Option 4</option>
  </select>
  <div id="dropdown_status23_chzn" class="chzn-container" style="width: 100%;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1">
      <span>Option 1</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</td>
```

My javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    startProgram();
});

function startProgram() {
    let automationStatusElement = document.getElementsByName("dropdown_status")[0].nextSibling.children[0].children[0];
    automationStatusElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
        console.log("dropdown_status changed");
    });
}
```

When I change the dropdown option - It changes `<span>Option 1</span>` text, but I can't get the event to fire `console.log("dropdown_status changed");`.
I verified `automationStatusElement` variable has the correct element. It just doesn't detect change.

Any help what I am missing here? Thanks

Comment: try using the id instead, something like this

document.getElementById("selectId").onchange = function(){
    var value = document.getElementById("comboA").value;
console.log('dropdown_value', value)
 };

Make sure to add an id to your select field

Comment: I don't have unique "id" on that field. I don't have control to modify it. I verified that automationStatusElement gets the correct element. It just doesn't detect change.

Comment: How exactly are you changing the value of  the `<select>` element? *edit* oh wait; you're putting the "change" handler on that `<span>` inside the `<a>`? Well there's you're problem; `<span>` elements don't fire "change" events. *Nothing* fires "change" events other than for reasons of user interaction.

Comment: Right, so is there any chance there is other js that is triggering on change then calling the preventDefault method which is causing your method to not be called.

Comment: Log what is in `automationStatusElement`; is that what you are expecting? Hint: hit's not a single element because you are using `document.getElementsByName()`

Comment: It's a drop-down, so I am opening and changing the drop-down. In the DOM, I noticed that `<span>` value changes, so I am looking for change there.

Comment: automationStatusElement is correct `<span>` element I am targeting. I verified.

Comment: @mykaf I think it is a single element—look at the entire line of code. It navigates from the `<select>` to the `<div>` to the `<a>` to the `<span>`.

Comment: You will never get a "change" event from the `<span>`.  You should put the event handler on the `<select>`, because it's an interactive element and that's where "change" events come from.

Comment: Okay, I see; `[0]` was hidden by the scroll bar.

Comment: I tried on <select>, but that didn't work either for me.

Comment: "When I change the dropdown option - It changes `<span>Option 1</span>` text". How does that happen? If there's other JS that does this, you should be able to add your `console.log` there.

Comment: if you want to detect changes to the DOM, use [MutationObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener)

Comment: Nice, tried MutationObserver and it seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this instead;

```js
const drop = document.querySelector("[name=dropdown_status]");

drop.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const selectedOption = e.target[e.target.options.selectedIndex].text;
  const span = document.querySelector("a > span");
  span.textContent = selectedOption;
})
```

```html
<td style="width: 25%">
  <label class="io-label" for="custom_automation_status">Automation Status <span class="form-required">*</span>
  </label>
  <select name="dropdown_status">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1"> Option 1</option>
    <option value="2"> Option 2</option>
    <option value="3"> Option 3</option>
    <option value="4"> Option 4</option>
  </select>
  <div id="dropdown_status23_chzn" class="chzn-container" style="width: 100%;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1">
      <span>Option 1</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make it work by dispatching a [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) yourself, when you change the content of the span.  For example:

```js
document.querySelector("select").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  let span = e.target.nextElementSibling.querySelector("span");
  span.innerText = "changed";
  span.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("change"));
});

function startProgram() {
    let automationStatusElement = document.getElementsByName("dropdown_status")[0].nextElementSibling.children[0].children[0];
    
    automationStatusElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
        console.log("dropdown_status changed");
    });
}

startProgram();
```

```html
<td style="width: 25%">
  <label class="io-label" for="custom_automation_status">Automation Status <span class="form-required">*</span>
  </label>
  <select name="dropdown_status" style="xdisplay: none;">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1"> Option 1</option>
    <option value="2"> Option 2</option>
    <option value="3"> Option 3</option>
    <option value="4"> Option 4</option>
  </select>
  <div id="dropdown_status23_chzn" class="chzn-container" style="width: 100%;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1">
      <span>Option 1</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: do you really wanna mix native and custom events with the same name? sounds like trouble

Comment: @mchl18 Sure, you could change the custom event name to something other than "change" if you find it confusing.